# SVN Branch switch

Tags: svn, version-control

We have a project and three developers working on stage server. We would like to do svn as follows:

1. Create different branches for each developer,
2. Each developer checkout from stage server to local machine and commit there changes to respective branches,
3. We would like to switch branches each time  a developer like to test their code in stage server,
4. Once all is working fine, we would like to merge branch with trunk,
5. Developers can update their local copy(respective branches) with latest branch.

How we can link branch to document root when each developer switch their branches(Point 3)? is there anything like post-hook?If so, how we can do that? I understand we can add post hook with trunk, so that it will automatically update with document root. But we are not sure how this can be done with branches and switching.

Comment: is document root *some* Working Copy or unversioned tree?

Comment: document root is /var/www/html and repo path is http://example.com/repo/trunk

Comment: But docroot can be WC of some path of repo or can not be. It matter

Comment: I'm not commenting here to be clever but what have described is pretty much 'git'. Master and branches can be swapped with little disruption. When a branch has been checked it can be merged in to master and then it automatically filters down to everyones master which they can merge into their respective branches is needed. Is there a chance you can use git instead of SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain what you want to do without the steps:

- Developers are working on code that goes to a server.
- A developer finishes their work, and can deploy it for testing.
- If the deployment is good, the developer can commit their code for others to use.

Notice I didn't mention branches. You can use a branch for each developer, but there's no real reason for that. With just three developers, I wouldn't bother with branching for development. However, some people like that model -- especially if they're use to Git and Gitflow.

What you may want are some tools that can help your process. Here are two you should look at. They're both free and open source:

### [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)

Jenkins is a Continuous Integration tool. Most people think of Jenkins as a place where code can be compiled, but it's very possible that your development environment doesn't require *compilation*.

However, Jenkins can do so much more than compile code. Jenkins can be setup to automatically *build* each time code is committed. Or, it can be setup to *build* at a particular time, or when a developer requests a build be done. Or, any combination of those.

Even if you don't compile, you might want to execute automated tests which Jenkins can do as part of the *build process* -- even if you don't actually compile code. Jenkins also can store a *build artifact* (such as the zipped up files you want to deploy), and can deploy those artifacts via a push of a button.

Jenkins has a whole slew of [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) that can be used to enhance your build process.

I am not a fan of using a version control system to deploy files to an HTTP server. I find using Jenkins a good way of controlling deployments.

### [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com)

Most sites I've seen have terrible development deployment environment. Most of the time, they don't even exist. Vagrant is a way to easily setup environments that can emulate your production and testing environments with Virtual Machines. Instead of having one staging server, each developer could have their own.

You setup with something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) a virtual environment that looks like your staging environment. Once this is done, developers can download the Vagrant file, and automatically install and bring up a staging environment. This can allow developers to test their code *before* they commit it into your Subversion repository.

Using Vagrant to pre-test changes before they're committed could simplify your process. It sounds like you want three branches (one for each developer) to allow each developer a way to test their code on your staging server. With Vagrant, developers could do staging testing in a virtual environment without having to commit their changes -- eliminating the need for branching.

### What About Post Commit Hooks?

The problem with post-commit hooks is that they tie up your repository until that post-commit hook completes. Imagine your post-commit hook *deploys* changes onto a server. That deployment might only take ten or so seconds, but that means every time someone commits their code into Subversion, they're sitting their waiting ten or so seconds with each commit. Developers will get upset with *Subversion being slow*, and will do fewer commits.

Using something like Jenkins to do your *post commit* work (via the build process) means that Subversion isn't tied up. Plus, Jenkins can make what happens much more visible. Each *build* has a console that shows you what was going on. If a *post-commit process* (a way to think of a build in Jenkins) fails, you can examine the log.

Answer (score 0):

The `post-commit` hook script will run whenever you commit, regardless of whether you commit to trunk or a branch.  In the script, you can check the output of `svnlook changed` to determine which branch you are on and link DocumentRoot to the appropriate branch.

You can find more details on svnlook in the Subversion manual at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.html